# handle lambda for @HTML.Label

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I Have a View stronger Typed, of my class called `Cliente`, Defined like this

```
public partial class Cliente
{
    public Cliente()
    {
        this.Campana = new HashSet<Campana>();
    }

    public short IdCliente { get; set; }
    public short IdDireccion { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public bool Activo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Campana> Campana { get; set; }
    public virtual Direccion Direccion { get; set; }
}
```

I want to add The elements of the class Campana, so I passed into my viewBag like this

```
 ViewBag.Campanas = db.Campana;
```

Now what I want to know, it's how can i Made a lambda expression to create labels, and fields based on the class. I tried like this but It doesn't work

```
  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Campanas)
  {
      @Html.LabelFor (modelItem => item.Descripcion)
  }
```

Here's the Campana Class

```
public partial class Campana
{
    public Campana()
    {
        this.Servicio = new HashSet<Servicio>();
    }

    public short IdCampana { get; set; }
    public short IdCliente { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public bool Activo { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Servicio> Servicio { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now what I want to know, it's how can i Made a lambda expression to
>   create labels, and fields based on the class

You can totally forget about lambdas and strong typing if you use this crap of ViewBag/ViewData. Not a chance. ViewBag is dynamic resolution that doesn't provide any compile-time type safety.

I would recommend you using view models and having your controller actions pass specific view model types to your views. Simply forget about the existence of ViewBag. It will make your code strongly typed and compile-time safe.

There are so much articles and tutorials over the www teaching people this cancer of `ViewBag`. I am really sick of it. Please don't ever use it in any of your applications.

1. Define view models.
2. Make your controller actions pass those view models to the views.
3. Strongly type your views (`@model MyViewModel`)
4. Use strongly typed helpers with lambda expressions and compile time safety in your views.

Conclusion: it's only once you have completely removed any trace of ViewBag/ViewData from your application we can talk about lambdas and strong typing in your views.

Comment: @KirkWoll, how can I not rant when I see ViewBag? This makes me not only rant but vomit. I see this so often when I do code reviews that I am really accustomed to this crap right now. Unfortunately no matter how hard I try people still continue to use. And that's Microsoft's fault for ever introducing this concept.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting that error is because you can't use lambdas on `dynamic` references. (i.e. `ViewBag`)  Now, you've said something about strongly typed views, but your view isn't actually strongly typed.  To do that, you use the `@model` directive.  You *can* declare your model like this:

```
@model Table<Campana>
```

Then instead of using `ViewBag.Campanas`, you can use `Model`.  Or you could just pass in the whole data context (`db`) if you cared to.   However, this is not very good practice.  It's better to create separate "view models" for your views and translate your linq-to-sql objects into your view models.

Comment: in fact, I did it, just i that don't added to the question, nevertheless, the View it's related to `@model Client`